# How to read integers from text file and put them in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, class, tuples

I'm creating a class which takes data from text files. Every file is composed by 3 integers each line and indefinite lines, like the following example:

1 3 5

3 13 8

4 5 10

...
Let's say this data is in a file called 'numbers.txt'. How can I put this 3 integers in a tuple, and then this tuple, in a list of tuples?

This is what I currently have (obviously wrong):

```
def _create_from_file(self, sky):
        """From a list of integers in a file, creates a list of tuples"""
        self.sky = sky
        f = open(self.sky)
        self.numbers=[]
        for line in open(self.sky):
            self.numbers.append((line[0],line[1],line[2]))
```

Comment: `f.readlines()` is useful here.

Comment: Does `line[0],line[1],line[2]` add only the first 3 characters of each line? Then `split` so you get a correct list first...

Comment: You're using `open` twice here

Comment: @G.Anderson: `for line in file` is Pythonically correct. See https://cmdlinetips.com/2011/08/three-ways-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line-in-python/

Comment: @usr2564301 edited, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def _create_from_file(self, sky):
    """From a list of integers in a file, creates a list of tuples"""
    self.sky = sky
    with open(self.sky, 'r') as f:
        self.numbers = [ tuple(int(x) for x in line.strip().split()) for line in f ]
```

If your numbers are floats rather than integers, replace `int` with `float`.